# Change Label.Text programmatically based on the variable calling the function

Tags: ios, swift

I am a newbie to swift coding. I am trying to write a clean code. I have multiple label variables I have designed. All the labels have the same UI properties. I am trying to write a single function that I can use for all variables.

I've done individual private lazy var declarations and built function for each label individually. But I am trying to use one function. For example below

```
private lazy var signUpLabel: UILabel = buildStandardProfileLabel()
private lazy var logInLabel: UILabel = buildStandardProfileLabel()

viewdidLoad() {

view.addsubView(signUpLabel)
view.addSubView(LogInLabel)
}

private func buildStandardProfileLabel() -> UILabel {

let label = UILabel()

label.text = "??" 
}
```

**How do I address the text based on which variable is being called**

I just want to use one function to call from both variables SignUp and LogIn but display based on which variable calls the function.

Comment: Is the only difference between the two labels going to be the label's text?

Comment: Yes. The rest of the properties are going to be same. And If I can accomplish this with Label I want to be able to apply to textfields and other UI Componenets.

Comment: why not make `buildStandardProfileLabel()` just take an argument as a param?

Answer (score 2):

You could make your function take a parameter for the text:

```
private lazy var signUpLabel: UILabel = buildStandardProfileLabel(label: "Sign Up")
private lazy var logInLabel: UILabel = buildStandardProfileLabel(label: "Sign In")
```

```
private func buildStandardProfileLabel(label: String) -> UILabel {
    let uiLabel = UILabel()
    uiLabel.text = label

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way is to set a tag for each label.
Define const such as

```
let kSignUptag = 0
let kLogInTag = 1
```

Then in viewDidLoad

```
signUpLabel.tag = kSignUptag
```

You can also create an array holding the strings

```
let labelTexts = ["Sign Up", "Sign In"]
```

then in buildStandardProfileLabel, use the tag to know which has called.

```
uiLabel.text = labelTexts[uilabel.tag]
```